# Labview Spectral Monitoring (USRP) - Bandwidth expansion and frequency change

Tags: frequency, bandwidth, usrp

I connected USRP (together with antenna) to my computer to receive some signals. For this purpose, I used the built-in module "Spectral Monitoring (Interactive)". Unfortunately I noticed that I'm not receiving almost anything. I wanted to change the frequency and expand the band, but I don't know exactly where to do it. Do I have to change the "Carrier Frequency [Hz]" from 915MHz to 2.45GHz for example, and do I have to change the IQ Sampling Rate (i don't know this term, I'm only used to Sampling Rate, not IQ Sampling Rate, is this the same?) from 200k to some other value to expand the band?

An overview picture from the GUI of the Spectral Monitoring (Interactive) module.

[image]